# Complex number equation 3

Tags: complex-numbers

This is a multiple choice question I have to solve.

If$$S=\{z \in \mathbb C \: | (z+i)^n  = (z-i)^n\}; \: n \in \mathbb N, n \ge 2$$
then

A) S has n elements $\forall n \in \mathbb N, n \ge 2$

B) $S = \{ (-1)^{n-1} + \cot \frac{k \pi}{n} |1 \le k \le n-1; k \in \mathbb N  \}$

C) $S = \{\cot \frac{k \pi}{n} |1 \le k \le n-1; k \in \mathbb N  \}$

D) $S \: \cap \: \mathbb R$ has no more than 2 elements $\forall n \in \mathbb N$

---

I know this is an equality of two complex conjugated numbers, so that means the numbers are real, so choice D goes off. I would be tempted to choose A because I see it as a polynomial equation of $n$th degree, but the answer is C. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps. For the first few $n$, the simplified equations are $4iz=0$, $6iz^2+2i^3=0$, $8iz^3+8i^3z=0$, $10iz^4+20i^3z^2+2i^5=0$, and $12iz^5+40i^3z^3+12i^5z=0$. You could solve some of these equations to eliminate answers.

Comment: $(z+i)^n$ and $(z-i)^n$ are not complex conjugate numbers in general. Did you try dividing the equation by $(z-i)^n$? If not, try it! Note that this quantity is non-zero, since $z=i$ is clearly not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer should be C, not D.

A is wrong because the you're solving $(z+i)^n - (z-i)^n = 0$, and when you expand out the $z^n$ terms cancel, so it's really only a degree $n-1$ polynomial, so it should have $n-1$ solutions (counting with multiplicity).

The original equation is *not* equating two complex conjugates; the conjugate of $(z + i)$ is $(\bar z - i)$. But in the special case when $z$ is real, then the two sides are conjugate, so as you say $(z+i)^n = (z-i)^n$ must be real as well. So $z \in S \cap \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $(z+i)$ is a real scalar multiple of an $n$-th root of $\pm 1$ (i.e. a $2n$-th root of unity) on the line $y = 1$. In fact $n-1$ of the $2n$-th roots of unity lie in the upper half plane, with arguments $k\pi/n$ for $1 \le k \le n-1$. A little trigonometry will show you that the real parts of the points with those arguments with $y = 1$ are $\cot(k\pi/n)$, $1 \le k \le n-1$. $\boxed{C}$

Comment: I am really sorry. The correct answer is actually C, Thank you !